# synchronization of jPanel's

Tags: java, swing, synchronization, jpanel, paint

I try to simulate swarm of drones with Java Swing.

The drone's flight as swarm by tracking IR points.

Every swarm member class extend jPanel and override paint function whose role is to paint IR points on its panel according to leaders position

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    for (int x = currX_1 - currIRdim; x < currX_1 + currIRdim; x++) {
        for (int y = currY_1 - currIRdim; y < currY_1 + currIRdim; y++) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
    }

    for (int x = currX_2 - currIRdim; x < currX_2 + currIRdim; x++) {
        for (int y = currY_2 - currIRdim; y < currY_2 + currIRdim; y++) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

the swarm leader and the drone beside him update the panels of the following members on every move

```
private void updateFollowers(AgentIrPanel[] screensToUpdate, String command) {
    int xdiff = screensToUpdate[0].getDiffX();
    int dimdiff = screensToUpdate[0].getDiffDim();
    switch (behaviour) {
        case SWARM_LEADER:
            screensToUpdate[0].setCurrX_1(screensToUpdate[0].getCurrX_1() + xdiff);
            screensToUpdate[0].setCurrX_2(screensToUpdate[0].getCurrX_2() + xdiff);
            screensToUpdate[0].repaintPoints(); // call jpanel.repaint() 

            screensToUpdate[1].setCurrIRdim(screensToUpdate[1].getCurrIRdim() - dimdiff);
            screensToUpdate[1].repaintPoints();
            break;
        case FOLLOW_LEFT:
            screensToUpdate[0].setCurrIRdim(screensToUpdate[0].getCurrIRdim() - dimdiff);
            screensToUpdate[0].repaintPoints();
    }
}
```

the following members get on their panels 2 IR point's and by recognized the differences from the previous points, decide which direction should they move

```
private String secRowReading() {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
    this.paint(g2);

    if ((new Color(img.getRGB(X_1 - IRdim ,Y_1 - IRdim)).equals(Color.BLACK))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_2 - IRdim ,Y_2 - IRdim)).equals(Color.BLACK))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_1 - IRdim + diffX, Y_1 - IRdim)).equals(Color.RED))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_2 - IRdim + diffX, Y_1 - IRdim)).equals(Color.RED))){
        ans = "right";
    }else if ((new Color(img.getRGB(X_1 - IRdim ,Y_1 - IRdim)).equals(Color.BLACK))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_2 - IRdim ,Y_2 - IRdim)).equals(Color.BLACK))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_1 - IRdim - diffX, Y_1 - IRdim)).equals(Color.RED))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_2 - IRdim - diffX, Y_1 - IRdim)).equals(Color.RED))){
        ans =  "left";
    }else if ((new Color(img.getRGB(X_1 - IRdim ,Y_1 - IRdim)).equals(Color.BLACK))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_2 - IRdim,Y_2 - IRdim)).equals(Color.BLACK))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_1 - IRdim + diffDim ,Y_1 - IRdim + diffDim)).equals(Color.RED))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_2 - IRdim + diffDim ,Y_2 - IRdim + diffDim)).equals(Color.RED))) {
        ans = "front";
    }else if ((new Color(img.getRGB(X_1 - IRdim - diffDim,Y_1 - IRdim -diffDim)).equals(Color.RED))
            && (new Color(img.getRGB(X_2 - IRdim - diffDim,Y_2 - IRdim -diffDim)).equals(Color.RED))){
        ans =  "back";
    }else {
        ans =  "stop";
    }

    g2.dispose();
    return ans;
}
```

the problem is - the following drones not succeed with this reading together, only when they operated separately. 
During the flight, one of the followers do not recognize on time the change that the leader has applied to it and stop, which messes up the entire flight.

I tried to delay the reading of each follow drone with Timer().schedule but without success. how to synchronize it to work properly?

Comment: ......................hello?

Answer (score 2):

> Every swarm member class extend jPanel and override paint function whose role is to paint IR points on its panel according to leaders position

And here's a problem. Don't do this. Don't have your sprites extend a "heavier-weight" class than is necessary, and that needlessly complicates your program. Instead have your Sprites be non-component classes, i.e., not extend any Swing or AWT component type, and instead draw them within **one** drawing JPanel whose paintComponent method has been overridden and whose `super.paintComponent(g)` has been called.

I'd give the Swarm class a `public void draw(Graphics2D g2)` method, create a collection of them, perhaps `List<Swarm>`, and then within the paintComponent method, iterate through the list, passing in the Graphics2D object obtained from the JVM, drawing each sprite/swarm object.

Other issues: be sure to extract the behavior and logic of your Swarm objects out of the GUI code. The logic code should be part of your program's Model, not part of the View (the GUI) whose job it is is to display the state of the model, and to allow the user to interact with the model (via the Controller).

Comment: I followed your guidelines, everything works great now and I learned a lot about the mistakes I made, thanks!